# why doesn't strlen (..) expect const char* const str instead of const char*

Tags: c++, string

I was reading though this: [const char * const versus const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char)

in `string.h`, [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) is defined as:

```
size_t strlen ( const char * str );
```

If I understand this correctly, strlen expects a pointer to a char that is const. Shouldn't it be:

```
size_t strlen ( const char* const str );
```

This would make sure that strlen cannot modify the pointer to point to a different pointer ?

Or, is this the case:

Since str pointer will be passed by value to strlen, any changes to this pointer in the function will not change the source pointer, and hence it's okay..

??

Comment: `strlen()` cannot modify the pointer you pass in, in either case; it receives a copy.  This would only be relevant if you passed in a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Those functions have the same signature. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645751/why-are-const-qualifiers-in-function-arguments-used-for-overloading-resolution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212932/defining-a-function-with-different-signature http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682049/functions-with-const-arguments-and-overloading and many more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really read that discussion, you should understand that the second `const` has no effect on the external behavior of the function. For you, the user of `strlen`, It simply doesn't make any difference whether it is declared with `const char *` or `const char *const` parameter. As you correctly noted, any modifications that `strlen` might do to the pointer are only affecting the internal, local *copy* of the pointer inside `strlen`. Your argument pointer that you pass to `strlen` will remain unchanged regardless of whether the parameter is declared with second `const` or not. (Your argument pointer doesn't even have to be an lvalue.)

The second `const` will only have effect on the internal behavior of the local parameter variable inside the function, preventing the *authors* of `strlen` from modifying that local variable. Whether they want to restrict themselves in that way or not is, informally speaking, their own business. It doesn't concern the users of `strlen` in any way.

In fact, since top-level `const` qualifiers have no effect on function type, it is typically possible to *declare* a function with `const char *` parameter and then *define* it with `const char *const` parameter. The compiler (linker) will still treat these declarations as "matching". It means that if the library authors so desired, they could actually define `strlen` with `const char *const` parameter. They are simply not telling you about that, since this is effectively an implementation detail or `strlen`, i.e. something you don't need to know.

Comment: +1, the standard is explicit in that the *top-level* const-volatile qualifier (in this case the second `const`) is dropped from the signature of the function.

Comment: @AndreyT: Thanks for explaining that so well, and also giving me a practical use case of how to use it with the `declare`/`define` construct!

Answer (score 2):

> Since str pointer will be passed by value to strlen, any changes to this pointer in the function will not change the source pointer, and hence it's okay..

Yes. It's only a restriction for the functions interior handling.

> This would make sure that strlen cannot modify the pointer to point to a different pointer ?

It's not needed, the pointer is passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

> size_t strlen ( const char* const str );
>
> This would make sure that strlen cannot modify the pointer to point to a different pointer ?

You explained the reason yourself : *strlen cannot modify the pointer...*.

It unnecessarily imposes restriction on the parameter, which could be used to compute the length *while modifying the pointer itself*, as:

```
 size_t len = 0;
 while(*str)
 {
   ++len;
   ++str; //error if `const char *const str` is used!
 }
```

See the implementation of `strlen()` in [glibc](http://www.stdlib.net/%7Ecolmmacc/strlen.c.html) which modifies the pointer itself:  by assigning it to *modifiable* pointer type.

See also [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlen.c?rev=1.7;content-type=text%2Fplain;only_with_tag=MAIN) lib implemtation:

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *s;

    for (s = str; *s; ++s)
        ;
    return (s - str);
}
```

Here `s=str` would be error if `str` is `const char * const` type!

Answer (score 0):

You asked the question because you know the differences like below (just to check):

1. `char` = writable char
2. `const char` = read-only char
3. `char*` = writable pointer of writable char
4. `const char*` = writable pointer of read-only char
5. `char* const` = read-only pointer of writable char
6. `const char* const` = read-only pointer of read-only char

The reason that `strlen` chose its parameter of the 4th form rather than the 6th form is practical; When we call a function via the function stack, the value of parameters is **copied** anyway. Even when it is a pointer type, the pointer value is copied. At least, the variable keeps the same type (just as C/C++ are type-specific languages) through the parameter.

So, the parameter works like defining a new variable with its own name inside the function scope, as soon as the function starts. When a copied pointer variable has its value changed (by accident), it wouldn't affect the original caller's pointer variable.
If you really want to control the read-write permission of the pointer itself, or to modify the pointer directly, you would use the double pointer. But, `strlen` is not the case.

As a result, `const char*` will prevent the copying of its actual content (we would never know the size of the string until reading `\0`) but it copies its pointer value (usually 4 Bytes) via parameter. Yet, the const keyword promises the function would not modify the value of the string.